# Correct display Cyrillic symbols in SublimeREPL PowerShell

Tags: encoding, utf-8, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublimerepl

### Summary

I can not to make correct display Cyrillic symbols in SublimeREPL PowerShell.

---

---

### Expected behavior

In Windows PowerShell I have not this problem.

[image: Expected behavior]

---

---

### Actual behavior

Cyrillic symbols always not displayed for me. I see [**mojibake**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) instead it.

[image: Actual behavior]

---

---

### Steps to reproduce

The problem is reproduced for me in a version of Sublime Text without plugins and user settings.

`Preferences` → `Key Bindings` → I change `Default (Windows).sublime-keymap - User`:

```json
[
    {
    "keys": ["super+alt+p"], 
    "command": "repl_open", 
    "args": {
        "type": "powershell",
        "encoding": "utf-8",
        "cmd": ["powershell", "-"],
        "cwd": "$file_path",
        "external_id": "powershell"
        }
    }
]
```

When `test.md` in my `E:\Киролайна` folder is opened, I press <kbd>Super+Alt+P</kbd> → I get actual behavior.

---

---

### Not helped

1. I saw in my PowerShell settings. I have `866 (OEM - русская)` encoding.

[image: 866 (OEM - русская)]

I [**change**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388500/5951529) encoding: I run in PowerShell command `chcp 65001`:

```
PS E:\Киролайна> chcp 65001
Active code page: 65001
PS E:\Киролайна> chcp
Active code page: 65001
PS E:\Киролайна>
```

[image: PowerShell 65001]
But problem is remained for me.

2. I try to change encoding in my keymap file:

   - `"encoding": "$win_cmd_encoding"`
   - `"encoding": "cp866"`
   - `"encoding": "cp1251"`

When I press <kbd>Super+Alt+P</kbd> in open file, I get error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8a in position 9: invalid start byte
>   error: UnicodeDecodeError('utf-8', b'C:\Users\\x8a\xae\xe2\AppData\Roaming', 9, 10, 'invalid start byte')

[image: CP866 error]

Correct path is `C:\Users\Кот\AppData\Roaming`, path contain Cyrillic symbols `Кот`.

---

---

### Environment

**Operating system and version:**
Russian Windows 32-bit 10.0.14393
**Sublime Text:**
Build 3126

Comment: Did you try changing the encoding to UTF8?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, yes, I try to change encoding to UTF-8 in PowerShell and in keymap files. See [**addition**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40541447/revisions) to question. Thanks.